# Como mostrar HTML adentro de "IF" javascript

Tags: javascript

¡Buenas!

Quiero mostrar un texto si un número es menor o igual a ("5") y otro si el número es mayor; el texto tiene que estar en **html**, porque en realidad luego lo voy a reemplazar por un `iframe`

```js
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
if ((ran) => 5) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "<b>Menor a 5</b>";
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Pero en sí, cual es el problema que tienes? no queda muy claro. Te recomendaría [edit] tu pregunta y explicar un poco mejor cuál es el problema que tienes.

Comment: Me parece error de sintaxis en tu menor o igual pues tienes los operadores al revés

Comment: el if esta evaluando una funcion de flecha(arrow function) `(ran) => 5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¡Buenas!

- Simplemente te falta un `else`, prueba de esta manera:
- También cabe recalcar que el signo ***menor qué*** **[<]** estaba mal.

También agregé un `console.log()`, para saber cuál es el número random que arroja, pero este se puede eliminar, también cambié el valor de 6 por 10, para que haya más probabilidad de que sea mayor, pero funcionaría con cualquier valor.

```js
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log("Número random: "+ran);
if (ran <= 5) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "<b>Menor a 5</b>";
} else {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "<b>Mayor a 5</b>";
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Eso y que tiene mal escrito el menor o igual deberías anotar también dicha corrección

Comment: Hola @dnlb , el error es tipográfico deberías solo comentarlo y marcar a cierre.

Comment: Gracias, es lo que busco, pero tengo un problema, ahora quiero eliminar la etiqueta `<b>` y poner un iframe, pero al hacerlo no se ve nada, probe de cambiar las comillas, y tampoco

Comment: @MatiPHP si esto no responde a tu duda entonces no deberías marcarla como aceptada

Comment: @Aprendiz Si, lo resuelve, yo me había equivocado al pasarlo.